# rollup bundled react development resources

Tags: reactjs, vite, rollupjs

I'm using `"vite": "^2.8.6"` for React project. What I know is that Vite is using Rollup as module bundler, but I stumbled on a problem where Rollup still bundling my `react-dom.development.js` and `react.development.js`. I've used `"rollup-plugin-replace"` to replace my `'process.env.NODE_ENV'` to production, but the problem still occur. Here is the my rollup config:

```
rollupOptions: {
      // https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#rollup
      plugins: [
        rollupPluginReplace({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
        rollupPluginCommonjs(),
        terser(),
        visualizer()
      ],
    },
```

When I analyze with `rollup-visualizer`, you can see that rollup bundled both `production` and `development` dependency, which supposedly only bundled one of them right?

[image]

The problem with this is that there is extra 1MB of dead code in the bundle, it will be great if I can eliminate it.

Answer (score 0):

This generally means that rollup does not understand that your app is directed towards production code. In my case it was because I had set up library mode.

```
lib: {
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  fileName: 'app.ts',
  name: 'AppClass',
  formats: ['iife'],
}
```

Removing this block finally generated a build which was sane in size. For more information, see the [vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-lib).

If you were also trying to get vite/rollup to build your app as an IIFE, setting `rollupOptions` worked for me:

```
rollupOptions: {
  output: {
    entryFileNames: `[name].js`,
    assetFileNames: `app.[ext]`,
    format: 'iife',
  },
  input: ['./src/app.ts'],
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer morgan, but i’m not building react library here, and the entry point that’s used is the default one which IINM index.html and it’s not supported by options `format`. Also about the build direction, I think the rollup should know that it’s directed to production `'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')` since it’s already hardcoded, and logically rollup should eliminate `’production’ === ‘development’`.